# byte[] length not the same depending on environment

Tags: java, byte, arrays

I need to have a static byte array in my Java code.

```
    public static final byte[]  TRANSPARENT_GIF_PIXEL   = {
        0x47, 0x49, 0x46, 0x38, 0x39, 0x61, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00,
        (byte) 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xff, 0x21,
        (byte) 0xf9, 0x04, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x2c, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x40, 0x02, 0x02, 0x44,
        0x01, 0x00, 0x3b
    };
```

In my tests, running locally via JUnit under Eclipse with Windows 7, `TRANSPARENT_GIF_PIXEL.length` gives me `43` which is what I expect.
Now if I upload my code to my dev server (Debian), `mvn package` it and run it and now I get `35` instead of the `43` expected.

I guess this has to do with the environment but I really don't know why this would differ as I explicitly defined 43 bytes in my code.

How can I guarantee to have exactly what I expect no matter the environment?

Comment: Neither do I, unless your code is not the same on each machine. Try using `javap` to dump the class generated.

Comment: I was shocked with the question as well, so I just coppied ur question and tried it on my ubuntu machine, the result was 43 as expected.

Comment: The point about java is: "write once, runs everywhere". In such basic features, like an byte array, there can't be any differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of no rational explanation for an array created like that to have different lengths on different machines.  If this is really happening, then it would be a flagrant violation of the Java Language Specification.

IMO, the most likely explanation is that (for some reason) you are not executing the same code in the two environments.  For example, there might be a classpath related issue which is causing the JVM to pick up different versions of the class (compiled from different versions of the source code) in the two environments.  Or you might have copied the wrong JAR file.  Or forgotten to copy a JAR file.

---

Another possibility is that the code you have shown us is a fabrication; i.e. your actual code is different in some significant way.

Comment: Well Stephen, thanks, the code executed was indeed not the same as it was sharing it's jvm with an other software that uses the same dependency but in an earlier version.

Answer (score 0):

Normally such problems might arise from

- Forgotten `flush()` when buffered class combined
- Text instead of binary transfer, throwing away CR, `0x0d`.
- Being read by C/C++, and 0x00 there is end-of-line.

In your case however it smells of using `String` for byte[].

Java text is in Unicode `String/char/Reader/Writer`. This is not so in C/C++.
It makes a distinction to binary data `byte[]` which are always in some encoding.
So a conversion from/to bytes *always* needs to specify the encoding the bytes are in.

```
byte[] b = ...
String s = new String(b); // Default platform encoding, non-portable
String s = new String(b, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
b = s.getBytes(); // Default platform encoding, non-portable
b = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
```

On Windows there is a single-byte encoding, hence 1 byte = 1 char.
On Linux oftern there is UTF-8, a Unicode multi-byte format, hence shorter, probably mapping errors too.

I personally would go to some length to use `byte[]` only, without the conversion from/to String.
It is error prone too.